# The for-loop only loops once, so it's like there was no loop used

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, conditional-statements

so first thing I'm new to python and I came across a simple problem but still complicated. Basically I try to loop all of the things from a list, and make them go through a conditional check if there the ones.

This is to check if a sentence is a greeting.

```
greets = ["Hi","Hello", "Hey"]

#Thinking
def isGreet(mes):  #Checks if it's a greeting
    words = mes.split()
    for greet in greets:
        print(greet)
        if (words[0]==greet):
            return 1;
        else:
            return 0;
```

When a user types in something, the code should check if it's a greeting, and if it is, return true, and if it's not return false. Simple, isn't it? But when I type in something, the code only returns true if it's hi which is used, but when i type let's say hello there, it would return false. I added a print function to see if loops works, but it only prints Hi, so I concluded that there must be something wrong with the for loop. Reaally appreciate any help.

Comment: why are you looping if you return after the first iteration?

Comment: just `return words[0] in greets`

Comment: Please take care of the correct indentation. Very important in python ;)

Comment: also avoid the semicolons. Useless in python

Comment: `greets` should be a set rather than a list.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I thought semicolons would close the if function, as curly brackets { } in C++ would do.

Comment: nope. I don't know who told you that :)

Comment: No one, just my stupid assumptions when I didn't know how do a multi-lane if statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The for-loop only loops once, so it's like there was no loop used

yes, because you're returning from the function no matter what at the first iteration. So your test works if the first word tested is the first in the list only. Else it returns 0.

no need for a loop, use `in`

```
greets = {"Hi","Hello", "Hey"}  # set should be faster, only if a lot of words, though

def isGreet(mes):
    return mes.split()[0] in greets
```

as stated in comments, `mes.split()[0]` is somehow wasteful because it keeps splitting other words we don't need, so replace by `mes.split(maxsplit=1)[0]` or `mes.split(None,1)[0]` for python 2.

Comment: I'd also recommend you use `mes.split(maxsplit=1)[0]` to avoid unnecessary splitting.

Comment: or `str.partition`. I'd like to keep that answer version-agnositic, though

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you expect the greeting to be the very first word. In that case you can do it in 1 line:

```
isGreet = True if mes.split(maxsplit=1)[0] in greets else False
```

Comment: no need for a ternary here: `isGreet = mes.split(maxsplit=1)[0] in greets`

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks